# Static IP Ubuntu Server on a VM

Tags: server, ip, virtualization

I'm trying to install Ubuntu Server on a VM, but I need an IP which I can access, at least, from outside of the VM (my local network).

I have tried the following [tutorial](http://bc-dev.net/2012/06/08/configuring-static-ip-for-ubuntu-guest-in-virtualbox/) unsuccessfully.

Running `cat /etc/network/interfaces` I got:

```
(...)
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.250
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
gateway 192.168.1.1
```

Even if I restart the network, I can't reach the address from my computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did that often on a windows machine, but I know that Virtualbox on Windows is very close to the Ubuntu Version, so I think the options should be the same.

In order to access your VirtualBox from the outside you need to enable a bridged network under Network settings.

[image: Network Bridge]

Also please enable remoting under display --> Remote Display

[image]

After you did that you can access the machine.